# Rails + PostgreSQL SSL decryption failure

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have an app running on my production server that uses the `pg` gem for talking to a Postgres database. Postgres is running on the default port, and is behind a firewall - so it's not accessible from anything but `localhost`. I haven't configured Postgres to do anything SSL-related.

I'm accessing the Rails app via SSL, and the certificate is signed for another domain, so the first time you hit it, a certificate error is presented...but that's the only thing SSL-related that's weird.

And yet, I'm seeing this intermittently in my Rails logs (accompanied by a 500 error in the browser when it happens):

```
Started GET "/admin/pages" for <xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx> at 2012-02-02 01:52:03 -0500
Processing by PagesController#index as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PGError: SSL error: decryption failed or bad 
record mac
: SELECT "pages".* FROM "pages" ):
  app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:36:in `index'
```

What the hell?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the database is running on localhost only, turn SSL off: it's not really useful to encrypt a local connection. Either set `ssl=false` in postgresql.conf (and restart the db server) or tell your client not to use SSL while connecting. Some installations configure PostgreSQL to use SSL by default.

Comment: For the record: i tried fixing this by turning off SSL renegotiation as proposed in other threads, but finally only turning off SSL as stated by araqnid worked for me. Bummer because i wanted to use the database server for remote serving as well :( Let's hope for a patch or an update that fixes this soon.

Comment: @JeroenDierckx: you can use "hostnossl" and "hostssl" in the `pg_hba.conf` file to enable/disable SSL based on IP range, so that your local clients don't use SSL but your remote clients do.

Comment: @araqnid Thanks for the tip, very useful! But i expect that the SSL reneg bug will still rear its head when connecting from a remote machine.

Comment: That's ok if in localhost. But how can I solve if I'm not on lacolhost and I haven't control on the Database server?

Comment: Thanks! `ssl=false` in `postgresql.conf` works well.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at your PostgreSQL logs you should find the same error. You should note that by default, after installing postgresql you will have the following lines in your `postgresql.conf`:

```
ssl = true
ssl_cert_file = '/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem'
ssl_key_file = '/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key'
```

Changing these requires you to restart postgresql, which may not be a good idea on your production system, since it will disrupt your service.

If you prefer to reload postgresql, you can make changes to the `pg_hba.conf` instead: by using the `hostnossl` directive.

Since you're using the `pg` gem, you can also force your app to connect without ssl, by adding this line to your `config/database.yml`:

```
sslmode = disable
```

In any case, you should probably adjust your postgresql configuration to use proper ssl certificates and not snakeoil, if you're ever going to need an encrypted connection to your database.