# Heroku PostgreSQL Connection reset by peer

Tags: postgresql, heroku

We are using PostgreSQL Crane plan, and got a lot of log like this 
`app postgres - - [5-1] ... LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer`

We are using about 50 dynos. 
Is PostgreSQL running out of connections with bunch of dynos? 
Can someone help me explain this case?

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting an 'unexpected EOF on client connection' as well?

Comment: yes, we also have 'LOG: unexpected EOF on client connection'

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing. Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've found the cause for the errors is the client not disconnecting at the end of the session, or a new connection not being created.

New connection solving the problem: 
[Postgres error on Heroku with Resque](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961044/postgres-error-on-heroku-with-resque)

Explicit disconnection solving the problem:
https://github.com/resque/resque/issues/367 (comment #2)

Comment: Yes, thanks, applying resque-heroku helped me get rid of this issue

Answer (score 1):

There's a Heroku FAQ entry on this: [Understanding Heroku Postgres Log Statements and Common Errors: could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgres-logs-errors#log-could-not-receive-data-from-client-connection-reset-by-peer).

> Although this log is emitted from postgres, the cause for the error has nothing to do with the database itself. Your application happened to crash while connected to postgres, and did not clean up its connection to the database. Postgres noticed that the client (your application) disappeared without ending the connection properly, and logged a message saying so.
>
> If you are not seeing your application’s backtrace, you may need to ensure that you are, in fact, logging to stdout (instead of a file) and that you have stdout sync’d.