# postgres error while using resque in local environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, resque, rails-postgresql

I have using resque for running background jobs, but I am getting below error. I am running application in local, I am not able to run successfully.

```
PG::Error: SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected : SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum WHERE a.attrelid = '"loans"'::regclass AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped ORDER BY a.attnum

/home/pcs31/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1158:in `exec'
/home/pcs31/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1158:in `exec_no_cache'
/home/pcs31/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:664:in `block in exec_query'
/home/pcs31/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in log'
/home/pcs31/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/home/pcs31/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
/home/pcs31/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:663:in `exec_query'
/home/pcs31/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1283:in `column_definitions'
/home/pcs31/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:859:in `columns'
/home/pcs31/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:12:in `block in initialize'
/home/pcs31/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:228:in `yield'
/home/pcs31/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:228:in `default'
/home/pcs31/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:228:in `columns'
/home/pcs31/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:248:in `column_names'
/home/pcs31/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:261:in `column_methods_hash'
/home/pcs31/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:69:in `all_attributes_exists?'
/home/pcs31/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:27:in `method_missing'
/home/pcs31/Desktop/workspace/cfs-web/app/resque_workers/document_worker.rb:7:in `perform'
```

I have followed below links 
[stackover overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961044/postgres-error-on-heroku-with-resque)
[enter link description here](https://gist.github.com/bleything/2511539)

sorry for my bad English.

can you please suggest any one ?

Thanks in advance
Prasad

Comment: Does that exact query get executed? If so, try it without the double-quotes around your table, eg. `'loans'` *not* `'"loans"'`

Comment: what happen does the other post did not work for you I mean did you do a reconnection on resque hooks

Comment: @bma: That's the query that ActiveRecord will use to figure out the table's schema, hence the ugliness.